# Find cell with max value of column, copy entire row and paste in row 2

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched the web for an answer for this but can't translate the answers I find into exactly what I want to do.

I want to find the cell in Range("L5:L" & LastRow) with maximum value, and copy that entire row and paste it on row 2.

I know the code to get the maximum value into cell L4. But I also want to copy the row which the maximum value is in. That code is below. But how to select and copy the entire row? Seems like such a simple thing, and I can't get it to work.

So this is what I have to get the value:

```
Range("L4").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("L5:L" & LastRow))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will find the max value, find the first row with the max value, and take row values from the max value row and populate row 2 with the results.

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngMax As Long
Dim rngTemp As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set rngTemp = Range("L5:L" & lastRow)
lngMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("L5:L" & lastRow))

For Each rngCell In rngTemp
    If rngCell.Value = lngMax Then
        lngRow = rngCell.Row
        Exit For
    End If
Next rngCell

Rows(2).Value = Rows(lngRow).Value
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this code.. I get that you dimension lastRow..and rngTemp and finding max with lngMax.. but you never say what rngCell is? So, I understand that the for loop will find the row with max value, and then sets longRow to take the value of the row with rngCell. But could you give something like an explanation to what is done in that for loop?

Comment: rngCell is a Range variable that is used to loop through rngTemp
For example, L5 is a single cell in the range L5 to L and the last row

The loop is checking to see if each cell in the range(rngTemp) contains the max value

If it does contain the max value, lngRow is the row where it resides